# php: sending mail from contact keeps throwing error

Tags: php

I am trying to use the below code to handle customer contacting via my site. It is not working and error is caught. the message I get "Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later".

The html form and the php handler are included below. both are in separate pages, contact.php and contact_handle.php respectively.

form:

```
  <div id="contact-form">
                <form method="post" action="contact_handle.php">

                    <div class="field">
                        <label>Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="text" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <label>Email: <span>*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" class="text" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <label>Subject: <span>*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" name="subject" class="text" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <label>Mobile No: <span>*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" name="mobile" class="text" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <label>Message: <span>*</span></label>
                        <textarea name="message" class="text textarea" ></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <input type="button" id="send" value="Send Message"/>
                        <div class="loading"></div>
                    </div>

                </form>
</div
```

Now the handler is:

```
<?php

//Retrieve form data. 
//GET - user submitted data using AJAX
//POST - in case user does not support javascript, we'll use POST instead
$name = ($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : $_POST['name'];
$email = ($_GET['email']) ?$_GET['email'] : $_POST['email'];
$subject = ($_GET['subject']) ?$_GET['subject'] : $_POST['subject'];
$mobile = ($_GET['mobile']) ?$_GET['mobile'] : $_POST['mobile'];
$message = ($_GET['message']) ?$_GET['message'] : $_POST['message'];

//flag to indicate which method it uses. If POST set it to 1
if ($_POST) $post=1;

//Simple server side validation for POST data, of course, you should validate the email
if (!$name) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your name.';
if (!$email) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your email.'; 
if (!$subject) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your subject.';
if (!$mobile) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your mobile No.';
if (!$message) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your message.'; 

//If the errors array is empty, send the mail
if (!$errors) {

    // ====== Your mail here  ====== //
    $to = 'fsa@gmail.com';

    // Sender
    $from = $name . ' <' . $email . '>';

    //subject and the html message
    $subject = 'Message from www.iso.com contact form'; 
    $message = '
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Name:</td><td>' . $name . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email:</td><td>' . $email . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Subject:</td><td>' . $subject . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Mobile No.:</td><td>' . $mobile . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Message:</td><td>' . nl2br($message) . '</td></tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>';

    // Send the mail
    $result = sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from);


    //if POST was used, display the message straight away
    if ($_POST) {
        if ($result) echo 'Thank you! We have received your message.';
        else echo 'Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later';

    //else if GET was used, return the boolean value so that 
    //ajax script can react accordingly
    //1 means success, 0 means failed
    } else {
        echo $result;   
    }

// If the errors array has values
} else {}


// Simple mail function with HTML header
function sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from) {
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";

    $result = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

    if ($result) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

?>
```

I hope you can help spot the error that I've missed.

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The `mail()` function is only as reliable as the mail transport installed on your server. In this case you should be checking the server's mail log for information as to why the message was not accepted.

Also, if you're not sure if the info will come in via `$_GET` or `$_POST` you can simply use `$_REQUEST` which is a mishmash of both, plus `$_COOKIE` if memory serves me.

Comment: mail function on its own works well. just tested that now with simple script. I received email in client. So something is wrong with this code

Comment: @sys_debug Check. Your. Mail. Log.

Answer (score 0):

Check your server's PHP error logs (where exactly this is will depend on your server setup). It will give you more information to go on.

That said, with the information that you have here, I'd venture to guess that your call to `sendmail()` is failing. The most likely cause of this is that the mail sender that PHP uses is not installed on your server.

You need to either make sure that you have a mail sender program set up, or use SMTP with another mail client (such as a gmail account) to do the sending.

Comment: mail function on its own works well. just tested that now with simple script. I received email in client. So something is wrong with this code